# End of Page Detection using TWAIN

Tags: .net, twain, scanning

I am coding a scanning application and I need to have end of page detection so I don't scan past where the document ends, does anyone what settings to use to turn this feature on for TWAIN drivers?  code samples in vb.net or C# would be great :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This appears to be a function of which version of TWAIN the drivers you are using support.  I had TWAIN 1.7 drivers, this version does not natively support end of page detection, so I had to contact the manufacturer to find out which custom capability they were using to support this.  The latest version (2.1 as of this) has a couple of native settings around this feature.